# Default value based on another argument

Tags: rust, clap

Is it possible to define a default value for an argument based on another argument?

For example in the following code:

```rust
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(long)]
    name1: String,

    #[arg(long)]
    name2: String,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    println! {"{}", args.name1};
    println! {"{}", args.name2};
}
```

I would like to have name2 use name1 as a default if it is not passed explicitly.

NOTE: My question is regarding whether it is possible (and how) to do that as part of the struct itself

Comment: I don't believe clap has a feature for that, but you can always use `Option<String>` and fix it after parsing.